# CSS Selectors like :after, :before not shown by printing

Tags: css, printing

i am coding and designing an applicaition and i want that the screen mode looks in print mode same.

Here is a screenshot of the screen version:

[image]

And here ist a screenshot of the print version (e.g. on Chrome):

[image]

The timeline stripe is set by :before and that won't be printed.

Have someone an idea or an solution? Have someone a guide for css print rules?

Comment: Are you sure your after & before rules are not in a screen media query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your css rules inside print media query:

```
@media print {
  h2 { 
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

Comment: put the style into the media print but it doesnt work

Comment: @media print {
  /* line 148, ../sass/components/_timeline.scss */
  .com-timeline:before {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #999;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
  }
}

Comment: and whats the problem? ^^

Comment: Here is it: http://caiokawasaki.com/trash/print-problem.jpg , you are using the color as background and if that option is unchecked it just does not show background colors.

Comment: that was the first solution which i had, but that doesnt work !important works, but its very ugly ...

Comment: I'm sorry, so do not know how to help you. May you have find a bug... What is ugly?

Comment: !important is ugly. it makes code unmaintanable. But it seems the only way that works. Chrome ignores the settings

Comment: Understand. Some things in chrome only works with Important! and it's not so ugly... So do with Important!...

Comment: i coding an application, so want to write clean code :D But thats the only way -_- but thank for your help :)

Answer (score 22):

I know it has been over a year, but here is what worked for me. When the Print Dialog appears, check to enable "Background Graphics" in the Print Dialog.

[image]

Comment: You are the best! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `::before` tag, seems like it is related to enabling background graphics as Abdud suggested above. I found that adding `print-color-adjust: exact;` to `body` solved it for my case.

```
body {
  print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Note that Chromium browsers only allow `body`'s descendants to have background color printed. If you have background color on your body set, this solution might not be suitable for you. [MSDN's has more information about how to use this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust#usage_notes)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to adding twitter bootstrap, in the print query there was following code

```
*, :before, :after {
  color: none !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

So i have override it by:

```
*, :before, :after {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-shadow: inherit !important;
  background: inherit !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit !important;
  box-shadow: inherit !important;
}
```

And after that: change the color of your elements by `!important`

Answer (score 0):

I had a `:before` pseudo-class with a `background-color` above a `div`.
It was not appearing in the print version.

I don't know why but the solution for me was to set a `border-top` on the div on them `@media print {...}` version.