# CSS problems with window.print() pdf styles

Tags: css, angular, frontend

I'm trying to modify PDF viewer of window.print() but I can't do it completely, my code isn't counting all pages and isn't counting well, is showing page 1 of 0, and in all pages putting page 1 of 0, for example, if I have 4 pages, it shows in every page 1 of 0, is not incrementing the number of pages, do you know some solution ? I know is there an library for PDF modify, but I'm using Angular 5 so is not compatible

```css
@media print{
    @page {
        size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin-top: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        counter-increment: page;
        
        body{
            margin: 30mm 15mm 10mm 15mm; /* margin you want for the content */
            counter-reset: page;
        }

        
    }
    
    html{
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    body::before{
        counter-increment: page;
        content: "Pag. " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 2mm; 
        right: 10mm;
    } 
            
}
```

I tried to put it like footer{} and doesn't work either, I tried to put inside @page too and nothing

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please provide minimal code example and focus on a specific question - is the problem css or the page number?

Comment: there's no error, just is not counting pages

Comment: You may wish to look at the answers on questions like [CSS Selectors like :after, :before not shown by printing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26972011/215552). You may also want to consider adding a proper element to the DOM which is set to `display: none` by default and only shown inside the `@media print` portion of the stylesheet. Pseudo elements are notoriously picky about when they appear.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you could add HTML and JS to your code snippet to demonstrate the issue that would be great!